# Scent and locating invisible opponent

Tags: dnd-3.5e, invisibility

The scent ability in MM1 states that at 5 ft. you can Pinpoint the sources location. Does this mean you could strike an invisible opponent without a miss chance? This regards Hunters sense stance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, the attacks still have the miss chance**

Pinpointing the location just prevents you from having to guess which square the invisible creature is in. You still have the miss chance — it says so in the [Invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#invisibility) description.

> even if an attacker correctly guesses the invisible creature's location, the attacker has a 50% miss chance in combat.

Invisibility is very powerful in 3rd edition, and just being able to pinpoint the square the invisible creature currently is in is a major advantage of a creature with the Scent ability.